# How can dock and undock Safari's Developer Tools in Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I am not able to dock developer tool in safari, when go for Inspect element (cmd + Opt + i) the developer tool is opening in new window.

```
Safari Version : 9.1.3 (11601.7.8)

Os Version : OS X EI Caption Version 10.11.16 (15G1004)
```

How can dock/undock developer tool in safari.

Comment: did you resolve this ? check my answer for any questions.

Comment: @ArunakiranNulu : Solution is not working.

Comment: When in its own window, Web Inspector presents another button allowing you to dock Web Inspector to the right of the window ,did you try this ? what happens when you do this ?

Comment: I have updated my answer , I tried it myself ,it is working , please let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is bug in this version, please follow the below instructions.

Close the web inspector,come out of fullscreen mode on safari,and open the inspector again. You will see the two buttons for docking the inspector at top left corner.